# Remove page numbers from the index which are related to \printbibliography section

Tags: bibliographies, indexing

I want to use `\index{entry}` inside of the bibliographic item. When I cite this item it appears in text on the current page (I use `style=verbose-trad1`) and also on the page where full bibliography is printed. I want to remove from my index page numbers related to `\printbibliography` section.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{a1,
  author        = {Aniston, John},
  title         = {Be happy},
  location      = {London\index{London}},
  date          = {1953},
  pagetotal     = {100},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{a1}.

\clearpage
\printbibliography
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: index]

In Index we see page numbers 1 (because of citation on the page 1), and 2 (because of appearing in bibliography). How can I remove page 2 from index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a new command, say `\citeindex`. Then we can redefine that command to do nothing in the bibliography

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand*{\citeindex}{\index}
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\citeindex}[1]{}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{a1,
  author        = {Aniston, John},
  title         = {Be happy},
  location      = {London\citeindex{London}},
  date          = {1953},
  pagetotal     = {100},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{a1}.

\clearpage
\printbibliography
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: Index London, 1]

Note that you can let `biblatex` index the `location` field automatically, e.g. with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1, indexing=cite]{biblatex}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}%
     \ifciteseen
       {}
       {\indexlist{location}}}
    {}}


\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{a1,
  author        = {Aniston, John},
  title         = {Be happy},
  location      = {London},
  date          = {1953},
  pagetotal     = {100},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{a1}.

\clearpage
\printbibliography
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps I can just add the line `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\index}[1]{}}` without introducing new command?

Comment: @andc If you don't want any indexing in the bibliography that should be safe. With a new name you can be sure that you only disable the indexing you added yourself in the `.bib` files.